# Get first related image from table while selecting all the records

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables in database

**Table 1: playlists**

```
id    name    user_id
1     name1   3
2     name2   3
```

**Table 2: videos**

```
id    name    media_id
1     vid1    4
2     vid2    5
```

**Table 3: playlist_has_video**

```
id    playlist_id    video_id
1     1              2
2     1              1
```

**Table 4: media**

```
id    filename
4     test.png
```

Now, I would like to select all the session where `user_id`=3 + first media.filename of video which belongs to `playlist.id`=1

See table `playlist_has_video` there is 2 video belongs to session.id=1
so select first video image only if there is many video belongs to that playlist

My desire output will be :

```
id    session.name    image
1     name1           test.png
```

Question is complicated to understand.

Comment: And what did you try? Also, define 'first' and what is session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
SELECT 
    pl.`id`,
    pl.`name` AS 'session.name',
    m.`filename` AS image
FROM `playlists` pl
    INNER JOIN `playlist_has_video` plhv ON plhv.`playlist_id` = pl.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `videos` v ON v.`id` = plhv.`video_id`
    INNER JOIN `media` m ON m.`id` = v.`media_id`
WHERE pl.`user_id` = 3
ORDER BY m.`id`
LIMIT 1
```